# Syntax and lists within lists

Tags: python, list

I am creating a vote system to pick a team, butI have hit a wall. The code works fine up until the point of `decision2`. Any ideas?

Please remember this code is a work-in-progress.

```
teamNames = []
teams = {}
easy = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
NoVotes1 = {'first' : 0, 'second' : 0, 'third' : 0, 'fourth' : 0, 'fifth' : 0}
NoVotes2 = {'first' : 0, 'second' : 0, 'third' : 0, 'fourth' : 0, 'fifth' : 0}
NoVotes3 = {'first' : 0, 'second' : 0, 'third' : 0, 'fourth' : 0, 'fifth' : 0}
NoVotes4 = {'first' : 0, 'second' : 0, 'third' : 0, 'fourth' : 0, 'fifth' : 0}
NoVotes5 = {'first' : 0, 'second' : 0, 'third' : 0, 'fourth' : 0, 'fifth' : 0}

while True:
print("Enter team name " + str(len(teamNames) + 1) + (" or press enter to stop."))
name = input()

if name == "":
      break

teamNames = teamNames + [name]

print("The team names are ")

for name in teamNames:
      print("    " + name)

for name in teamNames:
teams[name] = 0

teamNames.sort()
print("In alphabetical order the team names are ")
print()
print(str(teamNames))

y = 0
decision1 = input("Would you like to enter a vote? (1 = yes, 2 = no)")
while decision1 == "1":
print("ok great, where did " + teamNames[y] + " come")
decision2 = input()
if decision2 == "1":
    teams[easy[y]] = teams[easy[y]] + 1

y = y + 1 


if decision1 == "2":
    break
elif n == "6":
    break
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: And exactly **what** is the problem? Have you indented your `while` loop correctly?

Comment: it doesnt seem to like the part where i wrote if decision2 == "1":
    teams[easy[y]] = teams[easy[y]] + 1 . When i run the code it just says "teams[easy[y]] = teams[easy[y]] + 1  KeyError: 0"

Comment: That means that `teams` does not have a key `0`, which makes sense because the keys are supposed to be names. How were you expecting it to work? Also you really have to fix your indentation in the question.

Comment: @AlexHall sorry i just copied and pasted it straight from python, teams should be a dictionary with all the teams the user enters at the start, and then when it gets to decision2, if the user types 1, the program should add a value of 1 to the team (y) in the dictionary teams.

Comment: It looks like `teams` is the right thing but it's not clear why you think that `teams[easy[y]]` would give you what you want. The syntax is legal and there are plenty of cases where someone would do something like that. But `easy` is a list of numbers, so `easy[y]` is a number, not a team name. It might help if you walk through what you expect to happen or why you think `teams[easy[y]] = teams[easy[y]] + 1` should work.

Comment: @AlexHall i did it this way because the way i have done it, teams is a dictionary so i cannot write 'teams[y]' but this way i thought i was getting round that, and it meant that it added 1 point to the person i wanted. Just to double check the +1 on that line is adding a value of 1 to the key in dictionary right?

Comment: `teams[y]` is fine if `teams` is a dictionary - you've already used that syntax when you said `teams[name] = 0`. But it won't work if you're trying to access `teams[y]` and `y` isn't a key present in the dictionary. The exact same applies to `teams[easy[y]]`, where `easy[y]` is now the key. The ` + 1` adds 1 to the value associated with the key `easy[y]` but there is no such key. Again, explain to me, step by step, in painstaking detail, why you think `teams[easy[y]] = teams[easy[y]] + 1` should work, specifically accessing `teams[easy[y]]` on the right.

Comment: @AlexHall further up i have y = 0, then after the teams[easy[y]] = teams[easy[y]] + 1 i have y = y + 1 so then if the decision2 does equal 1, whichever team y is, so for example the first time it is run, y will be 0 and so that will be 0 in the list easy which will be the first team in teams will get 1 point/vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you've misunderstood. Standard dictionaries, unlike lists, have no concept of order or the nth (e.g. first) item. They are just associations between keys and values. When you say `teams[key] = value` you are setting the value at `key`, when you say `value = teams[key]` you are getting the value at `key`. It's possible that `key` is a number but it doesn't have to be, and if `key` is 1 then that doesn't mean the second value in the dictionary, or the first, or any other *position*. Perhaps this example interactive session will help you understand:

```
>>> dictionary = {"a": "b", "c": "d"}
>>> dictionary = {"a": "b", "c": "d", 5: "e"}
>>> dictionary[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 1
>>> dictionary["c"]
'd'
>>> dictionary[5]
'e'
```

What you want is `teams[teamNames[y]] = teams[teamNames[y]] + 1`, which by the way can be shortened to `teams[teamNames[y]] += 1`.

Does all that make sense? If not I suggest doing some simple experiments with dictionaries until you understand them better. Play around with the in the shell. Write some small programs using dictionaries to see what they do.

Comment: ok i have worked on it and got this so far. How would i loop the code back to the start to ask another vote? i thought that the while loop would loop again until decision1 = 2, or something different from 1. heres the code http://puu.sh/l5Gwx/8acc8cd8be.png  http://puu.sh/l5Gxn/21d6532410.png http://puu.sh/l5GxT/f663d84a7d.png THESE ARE 3 SSs

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it. Read about debugging with python (e.g. print statements, pdb, asserts, etc.) and try applying them. Create a minimal program that loops asking for user input and still exhibits the problem without the distracting context. If you're still stuck then post the program in a new question.